# Encryption Unsuccessful even after system backup restore

Tags: rom-flashing, twrp, encryption, supersu

The steps I performed:

1. Flashed TWRP with Odin
2. Made backup
3. Flashed LineageOS 14.1 with TWRP
4. Flashed SuperSU with TWRP
5. Flashed Open GApps with TWRP
6. There was a problem, Google Play Services kept crashing, I decided to restore stock ROM
7. Restored the backup I made in *2* with TWRP
8. Opened my restored system and decided to encrypt the device
9. Either the encryption failed itself or I somehow disturbed it
10. After restart Encryption Unsuccessful keeps appearing
11. I restored backup from *2* again I still get Encryption Unsuccessful
12. I flashed LineageOS again - started nicely
13. Once again I restored backup from *2* again I still get Encryption Unsuccessful

In the meantime I wiped `Cache`, `Dalvik Cache`, `Data` and `System` numerous times.

So it looks like the stock ROM keeps seeing the information about the failed encryption process even though I wiped the 4 partitions mentioned above. Interesting part is that LineageOS doesn't care.

Any ideas on how to get the stock ROM back on its feet?

**EDIT**

Flashing the stock rom with Odin didn't help either

Comment: What type of backup did you made (how did you do the backup)?

Comment: @Robert via TWRP "backup" function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out the way to fix it:

1. Download stock firmware (`*.tar.md5`)
2. Flash it **with Odin** (it removes TWRP and replaces it with a standard recovery)
3. Start Android - still "Unsuccessful encryption" error
4. Boot into recovery mode (now it's standard recovery instead of TWRP)
5. Run factory reset
6. Start Android - now it finally starts - problem solved
7. Flash again TWRP with Odin
8. Restore the old good backup with TWRP
9. Done

So basically the factory reset form the **original** recovery mode fixes it.

Also I found out why the tablet bricked. When it performs encryption process it looks like it's off (no lights, sounds or anything). Do **not** disturb it, after 20-30 minutes it finishes the encryption and turns itself on. Just leave it be until the screen turns on.